# Styling sub menu items with joomla 3.2

Tags: css, joomla

How can I style my sub menu items? I have a custom made template, one module and one main menu, the sub menu items are all set as a child of the main menu.

My problem is that I don't know what to refer to when styling them. I could style all "nav-child unstyled small" or make classes using the li class number, i.e. ".item-134"
(I got these tags from the source code displayed by my browser).

Neither of these seem to be nice solution, is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: It all depends on the code. You would actually need to post the html for anyone to help you.

Comment: You just need to double up selectors, so `.nav .nav-child .nav-child` will get the second level children. Note though that `.nav .nav-child` will also affect that level, but the one with the doubled class is more specific so it will override identical attributes.

Comment: @DavidFritsch it works perfectly but I have two different parents and would like to style the children of both independently...
(If you look at the site it's the two parents I am referring to are "information" and "about"

Comment: For those, you will have to use the `.item-119` and `.item-120` classes at the start. Obviously that will break if you use new menu items, since the number is based on the id of the menu item. However, it is really the only way to grab a specific parent in your current css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Fritsch is correct by using the menu-id classes to help select. Another alternative if you're worried about changing ID numbers is to use CSS3 nth-child selectors. You'll end up with something like:

```
.nav > li:nth-child(3) .nav-child {}
```

This will select the 3rd top-level item and then the child-items beneath it, and it's ID-free.